# Cant view the list of devices

Tags: swiftui

I have a json-result that I get from my own "api". In this I have a list of different devices, that I like to view in a list.

When I add the ForEach, then I get the following error:

> Generic struct 'List' requires that 'some AccessibilityRotorContent' conform to 'View'

The JsonResponse:

```
[{"name":"Tormek-T8","topHorizontal":55,"topVertical":55,"frontHorizontal":44,"frontVertical":44},{"name":"SH-332","topHorizontal":77,"topVertical":77,"frontHorizontal":88,"frontVertical":88}]
```

Can it be, that there are numbers in this JSON-String and not all is a String?

In my very simple code I had made a struct for the single Device and try to pull it from the url. Why I would get this error? Because the response of the JSON is not nil.

```
struct Device: Hashable, Codable {
    let name: String
    let topHorizontal: Double
    let topVertical: Double
    let frontHorizontal: Double
    let frontVertical: Double
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var devices: [Device] = []
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://cdn.rowoco.de/grindcalculator/devices") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let devices = try JSONDecoder().decode([Device].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.devices = devices
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}


struct CdnDevicesListView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.devices, id: \.self) { device in
                    device.name
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("cdn devices")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: `Text(device.name)`. And - unrelated – I recommend `id: \.name` or another unique *single* value.

Comment: Oh my godness. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach`'s content needs to be a `View`.

`device.name` is not a `View`.